# Multiline if statement Haskell

Tags: haskell, if-statement

I am writing a simple program in Haskell, and have the following function:

```
tryMove board player die = do
  let moves = getMoves board player die
  putStrLn ("Possible columns to move: " ++ (show $ moves))

  if not $ null moves then
    let col = getOkInput $ moves
    putStrLn " "
    return $ step board (getMarker player) col firstDie
  else
    putStrLn ("No possible move using "++(show die)++"!")
    return board
```

It takes a board, and if a player can make a move based on a die roll, the new board is returned, otherwise the old board is returned.

However, haskell won't let me use multiple lines in my if statement. Is it possible to use some kind of limiter so that I can use stuff like `let` in an if?

Comment: Style: `"Possible columns to move: " ++ (show $ moves)` can be simplified to `"Possible columns to move: " ++ show moves`. Don't use `$` when there's a single variable on its right: it's redundant.

Comment: @chi: Thanks! Should have used hlint before I posted ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to repeat the `do` keyword on each `then`/`else` branch.

```
whatever = do
  step1
  step2
  if foo
    then do
      thing1
      thing2
      thing3
    else do
      thing5
      thing6
      thing7
      thing8
```

Comment: You should add the reason why this is needed.

Comment: @bheklilr AFAIK, it's needed "because the language specification says so".

Comment: I would say that it's more because each clause of an `if-then-else` has to be a valid construct on its own (with scoping), and `thing1; thing2; thing3` isn't a valid construct, but `do thing1; thing2; thing3` is.

Comment: Alternatively, you could say that it has to be `if <expr> then <expr> else <expr>`.  OP's formatting doesn't work because three monadic expressions in a row don't form a valid expression without the `do`.